# Copy to clipboard certain dom element via javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Well, to solve an issue of accessing a certain Dom element via selenium and python seems slow.
I would like to **copy a certain element** (Text based) of a website **to clipboard** via javascript.

Please to be noted I have little to no experience using javascript.

For example,  i want to copy all the html content of this specified id `question-summary-67330422` to my clipboard. In my case the contents are text only.

[image]

Comment: How do you "copy and element?" Do you want to copy element outerHTML? What about a website? How do you "copy a website?"

Comment: Are you trying to copy a screenshot? Or the text? or what? Question is too vague.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am pretty new here. So, sorry for inconvenience. Updated the question, hope it might make more sense now.